# Permissão em PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou limitar a quantidade de postagens de um usuário em um serviço então criei a função:

```
 function limite($conexao, $id) {

    $query = "select cont_post from usuarios where id={$id}";

    return mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
  }
```

e na lógica de cadastro fiz a condição:

```
$numLimite = limite($conexao, $id);

  if($numLimite['cont_post'] >= 5) {

    header("Location: profile.php?=Limite");
  }else{

      $id_empresa = $_POST['id_empresa'];
      $localizacao = $_POST['localizacao'];
      $img = $_FILES['img'];
      $titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
      $texto = $_POST['texto'];
      $telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
      $email = $_POST['email'];
      $site = $_POST['site'];

      if(isset($_FILES['img'])) {
        $nomes = $img['name'];
        $tiposPermitidos = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'];
        $tamanho = $marca['size'];
        $extensao = explode('.', $nomes);
        $extensao = end($extensao);
        $novoNome = rand().'.'.$extensao;

        if(in_array($extensao, $tiposPermitidos)) {
          if($tamanho > 2000000) {
            echo "tamanho exede o limite perfimitido";
          } else {
            $mover = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], 'envios/'.$novoNome);
            //echo "<img src='envios/$novoNome'>";
          }
        } else {
         echo "tipo de arquivo inválido";
        }
      }

      cadastraFolder($conexao, $id_empresa, $localizacao, $novoNome, $titulo, $texto, $telefone, $email, $site);
      cont_post($conexao, $id, null);

      header("Location: profile.php");
      }
```

Porém não está funcionando, alguém pode me ajudar? Grato

Comment: Algum erro, o que não funciona?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Falta extrair as linhas do banco de dados com `mysqli_fetch()`. `mysqli_query()` retorna um resource ou um false, jogar isso em comparação não dá o resultado esperado.

```
function limite($conexao, $id) {
   $sql = "select cont_post from usuarios where id={$id}";
   $query = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
   return mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
}
```

Lembre de comparar o campo correto no if.

```
$numLimite = limite($conexao, $id);
if($numLimite['cont_post'] >= 5) {
   header("Location: profile.php?=Limite");
}else{
```

Comment: Olá @rray, obrigado por responder. Fiz a alteração no meu código e alterei a publicação aqui no fórum conforme o que você respondeu, mas continua não funcionando. Pode analisar novamente? Obrigado

Comment: @FrancisVagnerdaLuz poderia detalhar o que significa o 'não funciona'? o código não cai no else seria isso?

Comment: Sim.. isso mesmo, não cai no else

Comment: @FrancisVagnerdaLuz antes do if faça um `print_r($numLimite);` coloca ai o retorno.

Comment: apareceu este erro 
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\toqve\interno\funcoes.php on line 61

Notice: Undefined variable: marca in C:\xampp\htdocs\toqve\interno\folder_sucesso.php on line 26

Comment: a linha 61 é return mysqli_fetch_assoc($query); e a 26 eu já corrigi

Comment: @FrancisVagnerdaLuz na hora colar o código mandei errado faltou um `mysqli_query()` antes do `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` já corrigi isso na respostas.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo seu tempo e sua solução! Funcionou redondo agora.